# Проверить, влезает ли товар в склад Laravel + sql

Tags: sql, laravel, запрос, проверка

Всем привет! Возник вопрос, как проверить, влезает ли указанное количество товара на склад. Если да, то добавить, если нет - вывести ошибку.

Основная инфа: 
Есть таблицы:

- alcohols(id, name_alcohol, id_type_alcohol); ->связан с alcohol_types по id
- alcohol_types(id, type);
- storages(id, name_storage, possible_places);
- storage_info(id_of_storage, id_of_alcohol, count); ->связан с alcohol, storages по id

Есть код:

```
public function insert(Request $request){
 //Берём данные из формы
  $id_storage = $request->input('id_storage');
  $id_alcohol = $request->input('id_alcohol');
  $count = $request->input('count');

 //Проверяем вместительность склада
  $check_places = DB::table('storages')
  ->select('possible_places')
  ->where('id','=',$id_storage)
  ->count();

 //Проверяем, сколько уже есть на складе
  $get_count = DB::table('storage_info')
  ->leftjoin('storages','storage_info.id_of_storage','=', 'id')
  ->select( DB::raw('sum(count) as count'))
  ->where('id_of_storage','=',$id_storage)
  ->count();

  //Проверка, которая не работает и постоянно выдаёт, что не могу добавить,
  //Проверка на вместительность товара
  if($check_places < ($get_count + $count)){
    echo "<h1>Cant add</h1>";
    echo "<h1>Count > possible_places</h1><br/>";
    echo '<a href = "/storages">Click Here</a> to go back.';
  }else{

    $check = DB::table('storage_info')
    ->where('id_of_storage', '=', $id_storage)
    ->where('id_of_alcohol', '=', $id_alcohol)
    ->first();
    if ($check === null) {
      DB::insert('insert into storage_info (id_of_storage, id_of_alcohol, count) values(?,?,?)',[$id_storage, $id_alcohol, $count]);
    }else{
      DB::update('update storage_info SET count=(count+?) where id_of_storage = ? and id_of_alcohol = ?',[$count, $id_storage, $id_alcohol]);
    }

    echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
    echo '<a href = "/storages">Click Here</a> to go back.';

 }

}
```

Так вот, не работает проверка, если $possible_places(вместительность склада) будет больше чем ('count'->сколько уже есть на складе-> + $count), то тебе говорят, что НЕЛЬЗЯ ДОБАВИТЬ, МЕСТА НЕТ, если проверка успешная, то добавить на склад. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Всё, решено. Кому интересно, вместо

```
$get_count = DB::table('storage_info')
->leftjoin('storages','storage_info.id_of_storage','=', 'id')
  ->select( DB::raw('sum(count) as count'))
  ->where('id_of_storage','=',$id_storage)
  ->count();
```

Я написал так:

```
$get_count = DB::table('storage_info')
      ->leftjoin('storages','storage_info.id_of_storage','=', 'id')
      ->select( DB::raw('sum(count) as count'))
      ->where('id_of_storage','=',$id_storage)
      ->sum('count');
```

Просто просуммировал всё из этого, и использовал.